# Eclipse CDT unable to resolve enum constants with particular names

Tags: c, eclipse, enums

Whenever I try to use one of a few particular names as values in an enum, eclipse for some reason is unable to resolve those names, despite the code still compiling and running correctly:

```
// MVCE.h
typedef enum things
{
   TIMED_OUT,
   NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS,
   WHATEVER
}
Thing_t;

--------------------------------------------------
// MVCE.c
#include "MVCE.h"

Thing_t GetTimedOut( void )
{
   return TIMED_OUT;
}
Thing_t GetWhatever( void )
{
   return WHATEVER;
}
Thing_t GetNotCmd( void )
{
   return NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS; // Symbol 'NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS' could not be resolved
}
enum things GetNotCmdEnum( void )
{
   return NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS; // Symbol 'NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS' could not be resolved
}
```

This issue first started happening when I moved an enum constant from one enum to another, like this:

```
  typedef enum
  {
     BUTTON_PRESS,
-    BUTTON_RELEASE,
+    BUTTON_RELEASE
-    TIMED_OUT
  }
  Event_t;

  typedef enum
  {
     NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS,
     SYNTAX_ERROR,
-    BUFFER_FULL
+    BUFFER_FULL,
+    TIMED_OUT
  }
  Result_t;
```

After that, this issue started occurring for all of the enum constants that had been in `Result_t` before I moved `TIMED_OUT` (i.e. this happens any time I reference `NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS`, `SYNTAX_ERROR`, `BUFFER_FULL`).
This is despite the fact that *none* of the original source code files *even still exist* — even after deleting every file in the project, this still happens in any new files I create.

Another note, is that no error occurs for references in the same file where the enum is declared:

```
typedef enum things
{
   TIMED_OUT,
   NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS,
   WHATEVER
}
Thing_t;

Thing_t GetNotCmd( void )
{
   return NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS; // No error from eclipse.
}
```

I've tried adding include guards and `#ifdef __cplusplus` wrappers to the header file, but none of that makes any difference.

Note that **the code still compiles and runs correctly**, so this is an issue with Eclipse, not an issue with the code itself.

This is in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, version Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a), build id 20171005-1200.

How can I fix this so Eclipse doesn't show these spurious error messages?

Comment: "when I moved an enum constant from one enum to another," --> looks less like a _move_, but a usage of `NOT_A_COMMAND_STATUS` in two different `typedef enum`.    Clearly denote the contents of `MVCE.h`

Comment: @chux The move or whatever eclipse CDT thought it was is the edit that appeared to cause this issue to start happening. None of that code still exists in the project. `MVCE.h` is the first half of that first block, and `MVCE.c` is the second half (I tried to label them using comments).

Comment: Try forcing the indexer to rerun...

Comment: @EugeneSh. how do I do that?

Comment: Right click on the project -> Index -> Rebuild

Comment: @EugeneSh. that appears to have fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Even though not the OP's problem, @Reinstate Monica's comment solved a similar issue for me. I had the same enum defined in multiple locations through the workspace: excluding from build the unnecessary ones allowed eclipse to resolve the values.